# How to you search UTM params using GA API

Tags: php, api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

So I want to use GA API to create some automated reporting/tracking system.

I have already set service api etc, also have run few filters & metrics.

But I have no clue how to search for campaigns, UTM params, Acquisition, Hit URLs etc. params.

I did refer [Hello Analytic reporting](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php) for service accounts.Using php api.

Is there any metric or filter like ga:newUsers or ga:session to get data UTM-wise?

Can someone please help with it? Even tutorials link will help. There isn't any decent documentation I could find.

Comment: The [Dimensions and Metric Explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) has the full set of available dimensions and metrics. what do you feel is lacking in the documentation?

Comment: The link to Dimensions and Metric Explorer contains no information about how to search only on the UTM part of the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to add 'filters' to parameters array passed to get function.

You can look for metrics and dimensions [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets).
Although not the latest version, but she syntax of filter operators are explained [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filters).

For example:

```
$optParams = array(
  'dimensions' => 'ga:date,ga:source,ga:medium',
  'filters' => 'ga:landingPagePath!@/admin/',
  'sort' => '-ga:sessions');

$ga_result = $analytics->data_ga->get( 'ga:' . $profileID,
                                           "2016-01-01",
                                           "2016-01-01",
                                           'ga:sessions,ga:pageviews,ga:bounces',
                                           $optParams);
```

Comment: Hey @kgrg, you answer helped a lot. Actually it was creating a lot of confusion between v3 & v4 implementation... I have integrated v4 successfully. It works great.
Only issue I have is to get VIEW_ID from api.. Now I am entering it manually..